# Razor form foreach returning the same id

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, razor, bootstrap-modal

I have a button that pops modal with text area. When I click the Submit button in the modal I want to pass the data to the post method (Description and OrderId). The problem is that the orderid is always the same as the first order. For example I click on order with id that is supposed to be 4, but the id that it returns is 1(as the first order), therefore I'm passing the wrong Id to the controller.
Note - The order.Id works perfectly fine outside the modal, the problem is when im passing it to the modal.

```
    @foreach (var order in Model .Where(x => Context.Request.Query["searchOption"] == "2" ? x.Status == "Completed" : x.Status == "Active")) {
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; margin-left:1em; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-top: 1em">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">@order.ServiceName</h5>
      </div>
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">@order.Address</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">@order.StartDate</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">@order.DueDate</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">@order.HoursBooked</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">@order.WorkersCount</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">@order.Status</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">@order.Price<text>$</text></li>
    
        @if (order.Status == "Completed") {
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    
        <form method="post" asp-controller="Orders" asp-action="AddComplaint">
          <!-- Modal Trigger -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                                    Add Complaint
                                </button>
    
          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  ***<input name="OrderId" value="@order.Id" />
                  <textarea name="Description" style="height:100%; width:100%"></textarea>***
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
    
        }
```

Comment: Place a breakpoint on input with order id or literally anywhere else inside the for-each and inspect what orders are enumerated. Another way to do it, is saving the result from `Where()` to a variable and then inspecting its contents, before using it in for-each.

Comment: For some reason the data passed to the controller is always the first item which is being iterated through the foreach loop. Other than that the foreach itself iterates the orders as it should. Note that if i remove the modal and bind the id to a button of type submit it works fine, but i have to give up the modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change like this(add i before foreach and add i++ in foreach,change the data-target of button,and change the id of modal):

```
@{ var i = 0;}
@foreach (var order in Model .Where(x => Context.Request.Query["searchOption"] == "2" ? x.Status == "Completed" : x.Status == "Active")) {
    i++;
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; margin-left:1em; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-top: 1em">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">@order.ServiceName</h5>
      </div>
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">@order.Address</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">@order.StartDate</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">@order.DueDate</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">@order.HoursBooked</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">@order.WorkersCount</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">@order.Status</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">@order.Price<text>$</text></li>
    
        @if (order.Status == "Completed") {
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    
        <form method="post" asp-controller="Orders" asp-action="AddComplaint">
          <!-- Modal Trigger -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal@(i)">
                                    Add Complaint
                                </button>
    
          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal@(i)" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  ***<input name="OrderId" value="@order.Id" />
                  <textarea name="Description" style="height:100%; width:100%"></textarea>***
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
    
        }
```